# how can i get woocommerce category title and afc filed value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my theme on home page i want to show call category name two custom file value. i tried so long but not success yet.

bellow will be my html code

```
<li class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="0.3s"><a href="#">
          <div class="textpos">
            <h5>Category Name</h5>
            <h6>custom field one</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="imgpos">custom field two</div>
          </a></li>
```

for custom filed i am use AFC
so custom field one value can get bellow way

```
<?php the_field('custom_title'); ?>
```

custom filed two value can get bellow way

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

bellow code i got in internet which can display categories name but i couldn't figure out how to apply my html and AFC value there.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                    'terms' => $product_category->slug
                )
            ),

        );

    }
}

?>
```

**UPDATE 1**

bellow is another code which almost work not what i wanted. i want title and now coming all category title and all products name too

```
<?php

$post_type = 'product';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) : 

        $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" );

        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
          ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a><br><br>
          <?php
        endwhile; endif;

    endforeach;

endforeach;


?>
```